# Why firefox display boxes different from Safari, IE, Chrome etc.?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I've been tackling this tiny but very annoying cross-browser CSS problem: For some reason Firefox displays boxes/input fields with different measurements from other browsers. It seems like firefox is somehow ignoring box-sizing: border-box and still measures the boxes by its own measures. What is the cause here? Is there any bubblegum solution to this? I'm ready for it.

What I'm doing here is dynamic jquery input field adder. The fields next to plus button are 'fakefields' which for some reason displays different in firefox:

[image]

Doctype: XHTML 1.0 Strict

CSS:

```
.fakeinpfield {
        border: 1px solid #C2C2C2 !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px; 
}
input#fakeinpfield3 {
        width: 320px !important;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 26px;
        padding: 0;

}
input#fakeinpfield4 {
        width: 135px !important;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 26px;
        padding: 0;
}
input#fakeinpfield5 {
        width: 135px !important;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 26px;
        padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you deleting your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it with box-sizing. Seems like I need to use different box-sizing for firefox, since it measures the the box differently (I also set the element to inline-block, but im not sure if this has anything to do with it in the end) More to read: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

```
input#fakeinpfield3 {
        width: 318px !important;
        margin: 3px 6px 0 0;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        box-sizing: content-box;
        height: 26px;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why firefox do this, but I always come across this problem, and the last time my solution was to set `border: none;` and add a (input like) img as background, faking a input field, this way every input is gonna be the same size.

By the way, if I'm not wrong, Opera have another problem with the size too.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like it's the problem with border and how firefox measures it. I've read that box-sizing should fix this, but either I fail to use it, or it just doesn't work properly.

Comment: i've tryied lot of things, like css reset, fixed values, css hack...the last one ugly-worked but not as ellegant as using a image.